# python - inheriting parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class A:
    class B(A):
        pass
```

This does not work. Why? How do I make something that behaves the same way?

By same I mean:

- The same `__class__.__name__`
- The same `__class__.__qualname__`
- `A.B.__base__ is A`

Comment: What error does it throw? If it's `name A not defined`, it's because the definition of `A` isn't done by the time `B` is beginning to get defined.

Comment: @TankorSmash: `line 2: NameError: name 'A' is not defined`.

Comment: Why are you declaring class B inside A, and having B inherit from A? I would think you'd want to declare B outside of A.

Comment: Why would you want this? Nested classes are already mostly nonsensical in Python, but a nested class inheriting from the outer class is exotic (though legal) even in Java, C# and the like.

Comment: Sup dawg, I heard you like classes.

Comment: `A` is supposed to represent a very specific set of objects. `B` is a variation of `A`. `A` has a method `b(self)` which converts it to a `B`.

Comment: @HristoVenev: That still doesn't explain why you need B inside A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not without workarounds. The first class doesn't even exist at the time its body (including the `class B(A)` part) is executed. You can define the two separtely though:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

A.B = B
B.__name__ = ...
B.__qualname__ = ...
```

But honestly this doesn't look like the best design or API.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation happens "inside out".  Class A is not created until *after* everything in its class body is done.  So at the time B is defined, A does not yet exist.

Your only option would be to define class B with some other base class, then write a class decorator or metaclass on A that looks inside A for attributes that are classes with the specified "dummy" base, and recreates them with A as their base.

The real question is why you feel you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just because metaclasses are amusing:

```
class GoofyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        dct['__qualname__'] = bases[0].__qualname__
        return super(GoofyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, bases[0].__name__, bases, dct)

class A:
    pass

#using python 3 syntax here
class B(A,metaclass=GoofyMeta):
    pass

B.__name__
Out[24]: 'A'

B.__qualname__
Out[25]: 'A'
```

And `B.__base__` is `A` by definition.

As for why you'd want this, I'm pretty mystified.  It seems like you can just use inheritance/composition normally like the rest of us :-)

(I'll also note that I didn't address `B` somehow being an inner class of `A`.  I *extra plus one* don't know what you're trying to do with that.)